# AWS Lambda with SQS Trigger, SQS Messages are not deleted

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs, spring-cloud-function

I recently encountered a problem with Lambda functions not deleting the SQS Messages after a successful execution.
I've set up a lambda function and SQS Queue as a trigger. Everything was working just fine when the trigger configuration was like the following

- batchSize: 10
- batchWindow: 30

However, I wanted to optimize and process more items in a batch and updated the trigger configuration to

- batchSize: 32
- batchWindow: 30

After that update, the lambda function started to be invoked less often and it looked like it was working fine. However, when I looked at the queue stats, I noticed something very very strange.

- Even though every execution was completed successfully, no messages were deleted from the queue. Previously 90-100 messages were being deleted every second and after the configuration change, it's now 0 and it's been going for more than an hour.
- And the messages in flight jumped ~30 to 4k.

I don't know if I'm missing anything here. I've looked into this [doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-available-cloudwatch-metrics.html) for the meanings of the parameters and this [doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-sqs.html) for the trigger configuration parameters. The number of messages in flight and messages not visible currently still rising. I'll continue to observe if it'll continue to do so but have no idea why it resulted in so dramatic stats. Again, the function is being executed successfully and the process logs are just fine.

I'm using `spring-cloud-function-adapter-aws:3.1.5` and `aws-lambda-java-events:3.10.0` dependencies but don't think it's relevant since AWS claims that setting up SQS as a lambda trigger, lambda will handle cleaning stuff after execution.

What would be the cause here, where should I be looking at it?

-- EDIT
It's totally my mistake. I failed to report that I enabled `Report batch item failures` and this was the source of the problem. I disabled it back and everything went back to normal. Apparently, AWS expects any type of feedback regarding the messages are processed. I didn't go through the documents on how would that affect the system and that hurt me here.

Comment: The `ReceiveMessages()` function that is used to retrieve messages from an Amazon SQS Queue returns a **maximum of 10 messages**. So, setting the Batch Size above 10 is probably causing the problem.

Comment: Presumably you've reviewed CloudWatch Logs and there were no reported errors.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I don't interact with the SQS directly, but if AWS lambda claims to have it as a configurable parameter and accepts the value I provide, I expect it to work properly. Also, can you point out to the doc states that the received message is limited to 10 messages? I think long polling allows up to 6MB of messages to be received in one batch.

Comment: @jarmod yes, there are no error logs whatsoever

Comment: While I don't know what the issue is, I am fairly confident it has nothing to do with spring-cloud-function (SCF) as we do not do anything special with regard to interacting with AWS. All that SCF does is represents Java Function as AWS lambda.

Comment: @malik_cesur, can you share your SQS config? From the doc, it is clearly mentioned that Lambda service will automatically delete the messages if they are correctly processed. Are you sure that your lambda execution doesn't go above the visibility timeout?

Comment: Maximum batch size is described [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-sqs.html#events-sqs-eventsource):  up to 10k messages per batch for standard queue with total payload limit of 6MB; 10 messages per batch for FIFO. Sounds like visibility timeout could be the issue as @brushtakopo suggests - the default is 30 seconds. If you don't complete all processing within 30 seconds but you do complete before the Lambda timeout, all messages will appear to have been processed successfully but all messages would become visible again in the queue.

Comment: From [ReceiveMessage - Amazon Simple Queue Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/APIReference/API_ReceiveMessage.html): _"Retrieves one or more messages (up to 10), from the specified queue"_

Comment: @JohnRotenstein, when coupling a lambda to SQS this doesn't apply. Lambda can pull way more than 10 messages. I worked with queue and been able to pull 30 messages.